# Quais as diferenças entre ASP.NET MVC e ASP.NET Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Quais são as diferenças e limitações entre ASP.NET MVC e ASP.NET Razor Pages?

Fiquei bem curioso, pois aparentemente as Razor Pages utilizam o padrão MVC, só que sem a necessidade de utilizar um *controller*, nem sei se é realmente isto, e se for, provavelmente não deve ser apenas isto.

Também tem alguma vantagem em utilizar um ou outro?

Tem algum indício de que ASP.NET Razor Pages possa crescer e ficar popular como o ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A primeira coisa que precisa entender é que o Razor Pages é como o MVC, não é uma tecnologia nova, ele depende totalmente da tecnologia chamada ASP.NET MVC, sem usar o padrão MVC. É uma forma mais simples de usar o MVC juntando o VC em uma única unidade, porque na maioria das vezes é suficiente.

Pra falar a verdade eu vejo pouco sentido no uso do MVC na forma como usam.

Você pode usar o MVC *full* onde precisa e Razor Pages onde dá. Não é uma escolha binária. Misture se for preciso.

O que muda mesmo é a organização do código. Pode continuar existindo um arquivo com o código e um arquivo com o HTML, mas tudo faz parte da visão, é como um *code behind* que tem no ASP.NET WebForms, você decide como organizar. Existem métodos para lidar com todas as requisições de forma padrão, não precisa ficar criando um método para cada requisição.

No geral acho que é isso.

## Por que existe o MVC?

Para modularizar, dar independência para cada parte da aplicação, lidar com rotas complexas. Então você pode ter várias visões diferentes, vários modelos diferentes e vários controladores diferentes interagindo de várias maneiras.

A maneira como costumam fazer a aplicação o modelo nunca muda, e a visão menos ainda, nem tem muito o que mudar, a não ser no caso do WebAPI que a visão deixa de existir. Pra que complicar algo quando é sempre igual?

De que adianta criar 3 camadas se cada mudança que você faz tem que mexer nas 3? Pra que serve esse padrão de projeto se ele cria complicação? Serve justamente para tornar intercambiável para responsabilidade. Se a aplicação não precisa disto, boa parte do argumento de venda se perde.

Mas hoje ficou fácil vender algo, basta falar bastante sobre ele e as pessoas passam achar que ele soluciona tudo.

## Vantagem

Sempre que você deixa de usar algo que não precisa está em vantagem. As pessoas usam muito sem pensar o porquê de estarem usando aquilo, estão apenas seguindo a receita que aprenderam.

Sabe por que sua mãe vai fazer a receita que aprendeu na televisão e não fica bom? Por que ela seguiu a receita. Mas não sabe como faz aquilo. Tem sempre fatores que não são iguais em todas as vezes que vai fazer aquilo. O ambiente é outro, a marca do produto é outra, a força do fogo é diferente, o tempo que demorou para atingir um ponto muda. Tem que saber o que fazer, não pode seguir a receita pura e simplesmente.

Claro que a ferramenta tem que ajudar, e agora temos algo que vai pelo caminho mais simples.

Há pessoas que dizem ter outras vantagens, mas de forma geral é [óleo de cobra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil) para a maioria dos casos, ou seja, só cura uma doença inexistente, é placebo.

## Adoção

Adoção é algo difícil de prever, eu diria que sim porque é melhor para a imensa maioria dos casos e porque há incentivo para o seu uso (é a aplicação padrão no Visual Studio para ASP.NET Core). Acho até que consertaram alguns erros.

[image: ASP.NET Core Razor Pages]

Pena que não achei o artigo do [Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/) dizendo que deveria ser a escolha padrão e só adotar o MVC quando Razor Pages não atende. Mas cada vez a Microsoft publica material dizendo que deveria ser o padrão.

Já que estamos no campo da opinião, eu sempre achei o *controller* um pouco exagerado pra maioria dos casos. Se o modelo for bem feito, for inteligente, e a apresentação souber o que fazer com o dado um pouco mais bruto, é só o que precisa. Claro perde a capacidade de intercambiar as partes, em alguns casos.

## [*Minimal APIs*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

De forma análoga o .NET 6 passou ter uma forma de API mais simples que a WebAPI que tinha *controllers*. Boa parte dois casos ela resolve melhor.

## Conclusão

Ele é como o PHP era no passado (que dá para usar ainda), uma forma simples de gerar uma página no *backend*. É uma pena que isso se perdeu, porque para a maioria dos casos é suficiente. MVC só é necessário quando se tem algo complexo, rotas muito flexíveis.

## Veja mais

- [Artigo na MSDN Magazine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/asp-net-core-simpler-asp-net-mvc-apps-with-razor-pages?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Documentação Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Postagem em blog defendendo o uso](https://stackify.com/asp-net-razor-pages-vs-mvc/)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Razor Pages possui as camadas de Visão e Controller unificadas, parecido com um *code behind*.

Em uma aplicação pequena onde não haverá tanta informação cruzada, vale a pena usar Razor Pages. Até sua ViewModel pode compor o back-end da página Razor.

Agora, é importante avaliar bem uma coisa: Essa pequena aplicação pode vir a crescer? Se a resposta for sim, considere usar o MVC, afinal, como já explanado em resposta anterior, aumenta o seu poder de modularização.