# Entendimento sobre MVC

Tags: php, mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Estou tentando entender o padrão MVC mas são tantos vídeos de forma diferente na web que bagunça o entendimento.

Eu, por minha vez, estou usando um padrão próprio. Mas gostaria de saber se está correto, senão, qual seria a forma própria.

Estou usando em *2 camadas de classes* e uma em uma arquivo separado.

Exemplo:

Tabela: Clientes

#### MVC/Model/Clientes.php

```
class Clientes {
 $id;
 $nome;
 $idade;
 public function __construct() {}
/**
  Getteres e Setteres
**/
}
```

#### MVC/View/Clientes.php

```
class Clientes {
 public function __construct() {}
/**
  métodos de gravação,alteração e leitura no banco
**/
}
```

#### MVC/Controller/Clientes.php

```
require_once '../Controller/Clientes';
require_once '../Model/Clientes';

$clientes = new Clientes();
$clientesLista = $clientes->listaClientes();
```

#### index.php

```
require_once "MVC/Controller/Clientes.php";
```

A ideia é essa mesma? Ou estou totalmente por fora?

Se não for está a ideia, podem por favor postar um exemplo bem simples igual ao que eu postei. De preferencia usando termos conhecidos como `class Clientes` e evite por favor exemplos como `Class foo`, `foo->bar`.

Comment: Na sua *View* você está colocando métodos para "gravação", e esse não é o objetivo da *View*, ele deve ser "o que o usuário vê" de uma forma simples, ou seja, ela deve receber a *Model* e gerar o `html` para o usuário. Os métodos para salvar/ler dados devem estar na *Controller*

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114824/como-e-para-que-usar-mvc-no-php/116392#116392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A camada **Model** é aonde ficam todo o "Modelo de Negócios" da sua aplicação. Isso inclui também ***métodos de gravação,alteração e leitura no banco***.

A camada **Controller** é uma ponte, o acesso inicial do usuário antes de acessar a **View** e o Model.

---

**Estrutura exemplo:**

- MVC/Model/

  - *Clientes.php*
  - *ClientesDAO.php*
- MVC/View/

  - *ClientesView.php*
- MVC/Controller/

  - *ClientesController.php*
- index.php

---

**index.php**

```
require_once "MVC/Controller/ClientesController.php";
new ClientesController();
```

---

**MVC/Controller/ClientesController.php**

```
require_once '../Model/Clientes';
require_once '../Model/ClientesDAO';
require_once '../View/ClientesView';

class ClientesController {

    public function __construct() {

        ClienteDAO cli = new ClienteDAO();
        $listagemDeClientes = cli -> listar();

        $view = new ClientesView();
        $view->exibir($listagemDeClientes);
    }

}
```

---

**MVC/Model/ClientesDAO.php**

```
class ClientesDAO {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function listar(){
        /// conectar com o banco
        // gerar a lista
        $arrayClientes = [

            new Clientes("Nome1", "Sobrenome1"),
            new Clientes("Nome2", "Sobrenome2")

        ];

        return $arrayClientes;

    }

}
```

**MVC/Model/Clientes.php**

```
class Clientes {

    private $nome, $sobrenome;

    public function __construct($nome, $sobrenome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->sobrenome = $sobrenome;
    }

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getSobrenome(){
        return $this->sobrenome;
    }

}
```

---

**MVC/View/ClientesView.php**

```
class ClientesView {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function exibir($lista){

        foreach($lista as $clientes){
            $conteudo = file_get_contents("../htm/template1.php");
            $conteudo = str_replace("{nome}", $clientes->getNome);
            $conteudo = str_replace("{sobrenome}", $clientes->getSobrenome);
            echo $conteudo;
        }

    }

}
```

---

**htm/template1.php**

```
<h1>{nome}</h1>
<p>{sobrenome}</p>
```

---

Você pode implementar mais de 1 Controller se precisar. Mas repare que o Controller apenas identifica a requisição e "conversa" com o restante da aplicação. Todo o modelo de negócios está dentro da camada model.

Answer (score 7):

Você acaba de descobrir o mundo maravilhoso do treinamento na web (e algum fora dela), principalmente, mas não limitado, aos gratuitos. Muita desinformação sendo passada pra frente, pouco questionamento e critério. Quando quem aprende não entende o que está ocorrendo ali, não pode avaliar se é certo e está cada diz mais assim, em tudo na vida. A desinformação impera e quem não tem uma base muito boa para classificar a qualidade geral fica perdido mesmo.

O que importa é atender bem sua necessidade. Dizer que fez MVC só por dizer e isto não ser a melhor solução não ajuda em nada.

Dá para fazer [MVC sem usar classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264129/101). Nunca viu alguém mostrando assim? Porque provavelmente todos que viu ensinando esse padrão não sabem disso. Eles ensinam algo que não entendem. Mas tem exceções, claro, pode ser apenas que seja a abordagem daquele momento que a pessoa está passando. Mas como saberemos?

O MVC não tem aplicação universal e muitos casos só traz burocracia sem vir junto alguma vantagem. Na verdade grande parte do que eu vejo por aí não precisa de *controller*, e ele está ali de enfeite. De fato isto é tão óbvio que alguns *frameworks* passaram oferecer alternativas, como o [Razor Pages](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275940/101) no .NET.

Nos casos onde ele é útil não deveria ter uma implementação obrigatoriamente certa, apenas uma adequada ao contexto.

Seu dois primeiros código parecem repetidos e boa parte deles desnecessários, embora não dê para afirmar porque está cheio de comentário e nada de código.

*Getters e setters* são necessários ali? Eles te dão alguma vantagem? Em *scripts* não costuma dar. Se sua aplicação não é um *script* provavelmente não deveria usar uma linguagem de *script* para fazê-lo.

A *view* deve ter apresentação e mais nada. Ali parece que vai colocar coisas que deveria estar no modelo, deveria estar no modelo ou em um serviço auxiliar.

O controlador parece ter começado direito, não sei se continuará, mas seu código não indica isto.

O exemplo não lhe ensinará nada útil porque será só mais uma receita de bolo que pode ou não ser adequado ao seu problema, que não está bem definido para poder dizer algo. No contexto usar `Clientes` ou `Foo` dá na mesma. Na verdade `Clientes` pode ser pior porque pode passar a impressão que ali tem algo prático, útil, quando na verdade não é. Quase sempre exemplo sem fundamentos prejudicam o entendimento, e este é um dos problemas do vídeos, tutoriais e pseudo cursos, além é claro, de livros caça-níqueis. Só se aprende quando começa do começo.

Aqui tem algumas informações, mas de forma muito organizada. Se ler tudo, seguir os *links*, consultar a bibliografia passada, pode se preparar para o MVC. Mas antes seria bom entender outros aspectos da computação e do pensamento. Tem alguns casos de falhas e buracos e até mesmo as minhas respostas não são lá tão boas assim. Alguns *links* (não assino em baixo de alguns):

- [O que é MVC (Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/101)
- [O que é a View no padrão MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168246/101)
- [Como e para que usar MVC no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114824/101)
- [Um model de usuário deve ter todas as ações que o envolvem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247037/101)
- [Como utilizar o padrão de desenvolvimento MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264242/101)
- [Quando o controller é necessário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60830/101)
- [MVC versus MVVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214658/101)
- [Pra que serve uma ViewModel no ASP.NET MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305207/101)
- [Diferença entre biblioteca e helper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54884/101)
- [Como funciona a estrutura MVC para aplicações Desktop?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85848/101)
- [Quais são as camadas de uma aplicação web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122309/101)
- [Diferença entre DTO e ViewModel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305301/101)
- [Alternativas ao MVC para aplicações Web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4474/101)
- [O que o Model pode fazer em questão de validação no MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67911/101)
- [Em MVC, se eu tiver classes de utilitários, elas farão parte dos models?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106924/101)
- [Qual o papel dos padrões de arquitetura em orientação a objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15916/101)
- [Por que usar o AngularJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123913/101)
- [Qual a diferença do MVC web para MVC desktop/mobile?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23668/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114084/18246 - talvez seja útil também

Comment: @LINQ Quer por?